# Need to import a python library into a webserver

Tags: python, import, sqlite

I want to run a python file on a webserver that uses the sqlite3 library, but I have no idea how to install it on my server.

Edit: We were using python mod CGI on a networksolutions server. For some reason, their Python installation didn't have the sqlite package. What I was trying to ask here (as a junior developer) was how we can pip install something on their servers - which probably wasn't possible since we didn't have SSH or root access to be able to run `pip install`. Nevertheless please ignore this question as it is very old and wasn't asked properly.

Comment: Do you mean: how can I run a Python script on a webserver (eg: Apache)?

Answer (score 3):

sqlite3 is part of the [Python standard library](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html). As such, if python is installed on the application server, then it will use that library. It seems like the issue for your question is getting your web server to use python. This is dependent upon many different things, beginning on your web server.

Here are a few starting points:

[lighttpd](http://www.jakehilton.com/?q=node/54)

apache [modwsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) or [mod_python](http://www.modpython.org/)

[nginx](http://kbeezie.com/view/circuits-nginx-uwsgi/)